# jstl core formatNumber type percent

Tags: jstl

JSTL core formatNumber type percent is remove precision values while rendering in UI.
 `<fmt:formatNumber value="0.25" type="percent" />`
out put : 25% 
where formatNumber type percent is multiply input value by 100.

Is there a way to avoid get 0.25% this instead of dividing with 100 ?

Comment: that is just the way percentages work, it means per 100 so why would you want to avoid typing 0.25?

Comment: I copy and pasted this questions url to my account the second you asked it, it will be there forever.

Comment: There is no poitn  on trying to avoid dividing by 100, as set earlier this is the way percentages work. Wich means 1 out of 100 wich is 100% correct for 0.25 wich is 0.25 out of 1.  Ask yourself the question what you win from it performance wise if you would avoid dividing by 100. I don't have experience with jstl but even if it was a build in feature they would do it the same thing by just dividing it to 100. Hope this helps.